# how do I encrypt an already existing external drive that I have been using for time machine backups?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, encryption, time-machine

I have an external drive that I formatted with APFS a long time ago and I use it for time machine backups. I am currently using Monterey 12.6 on my Mac book pro

I would like to 'switch to'  encryption for backing up. that means somehow encrypting the files that are already on this hard drive as well as making sure Time machine uses encryption for future backups

documentation online doesn't help.   e.g. one apple page says to control click on the drive in finder and you will see an encryption option... I did not

Comment: From my initial research, I don't see a way to encrypt the existing backup in place using Time Machine. You have to start from scratch (per MacWorld). You may have to get a second drive, and perform the encrypted backup operations to the new drive. Then, you can copy the old drive contents to the new drive. Then you can wipe, encrypt, and perform a second backup to the old drive, to keep a secondary encrypted copy of the backups. You would want a backup copy of your sensitive and important data prior to performing any type of operation, like encryption, on the data.

Comment: wow. that is a lot of work.  hey , taking time machine out of the equation for a second... if this is just an external drive of general data and i want to encrypt it 'in place' ... is that possible?

Comment: If there's no Time Machine on it, you can just right-click/encrypt.